# Representative as in for contracts

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am filling a form for staying on-campus on my university.
I am trying to figure out what the word representative means in this context.

Referring to item 4.
http://www.rta.qld.gov.au/zone_files/rooming_accommodation/r18.pdf

Dictionary:
"**Representative** - a person or thing that represents another or others."

What can I actually fill in here? I actually wrote myself, because no one is representing me.

Did I get the wrong idea?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you refer to *representative* in item 4.1, "Resident’s Representative for Notices (see clause 29)".  In clause 29, on page 6, we find:

> (9) In this clause –
>   representative means a person acting for the resident under
>   section 525(1)(c).

If you have a permanent address where "notices" -- whatever they might be -- should be sent, then you can designate a person at that address as an agent to receive notices at that address, on your behalf.

*Comment*-- Given all the legalistic language the document is stuffed with, you probably should telephone or email the university's housing department and discuss the form with them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is someone else who can receive notices for you, you are your own representative.